# how to display popup beside link

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have this CSS setup of my DIV:

```
<div style="width: 380px; background: #fff; margin: 0 auto; position:relative; margin-top: 200px;">...</div>
```

When I click on the link, so the DIV above will be displayed. What I don't like - it will be displayed always on the same place in the browser. But I would like to show this DIV for example **10px** beside the link, on that I clicked.

Could anyone help me please, how to do?

Comment: If I get it right, you will need Javascript to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="">Link to popup</a>
<div style="display:inline; margin-left:10px;">…</div>
```

Would something this simple work?

Otherwise you could play around with wrapping the link and the div, setting the wrapping div to `position:relative;` and position the div with `position:absolute;`

I can demo that for you too, if that would be helpful.